# Как сделать подсказки для меню команд в telegram'е Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сделать такое меню на aiogram?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна `bot.set_my_commands(...)`

```
from aiogram.types import BotCommand


async def setup_bot_commands():
    bot_commands = [
        BotCommand(command="/help", description="Get info about me"),
        BotCommand(command="/qna", description="set bot for a QnA task"),
        BotCommand(command="/chat", description="set bot for free chat")
    ]
    await bot.set_my_commands(bot_commands)

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=setup_bot_commands)
```

Answer (score -1):

@BotFather -> MyBot -> Edit Bot -> Edit commands